# Can a website located on a subdomain affect my main domain for duplicated meta description?

Tags: seo, subdomain, meta-tags, meta-description

I have 2 websites, the main website located at `example.com`, and another one which is on `a.example.com`.

The problem is that I have some duplicated meta description problems to the website located on the subdomain and I can't solve them right now.

Will they affect my SEO rankings to my main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because subdomains (like `a.example.com`) are considered by search engines as different websites in relation to the main domain (`example.com`).

Therefore, having duplicated meta description in several pages of the same website can be a problem for this website (for example `a.example.com`) but it doesn't affect another website.

Otherwise, two duplicated meta description on two different websites is not a problem. It's normal to think that two websites can speak about the same thing and have by accident the same meta description.

Comment: I asked this because when I searched for site:example.com on google, the second search result was a.example.com.